# Programmatically get column lengths using vertica_python driver

Tags: python, sql, vertica

Is it possible to run commands like `\d schema.table_name;` through vertica_python? I run into the following error indicating it doesn't like the leading backslash:

```
vertica_python.errors.VerticaSyntaxError: Severity: ERROR, Message: Syntax error at or near "\", Sqlstate: 42601, Position: 1, Routine: base_yyerror, File: /scratch_a/release/svrtar9988/vbuild/vertica/Parser/scan.l, Line: 1043, SQL: '\\d schema.table_name;'
```

I'm essentially trying to get the lengths of a few VARCHAR columns in my program. I could always put the command in a file, run `vertica -f my_file > out_file` and parse the out_file but I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute a query against the system views ([`COLUMNS`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/COLUMNS.htm)). Something like:

```
select *
from columns
where table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA'
and   table_name = 'MYTABLE'
order by column_id
```

`\d` is a `vsql` command, not a server-side command.

Another possibility since you are using `vertica_python` is to inspect the fields from the cursor after you execute a query. Useful if you already have a resultset and want to know the data types.  I probably would only use this method if you already have a result, though.

To do that, you can look at `cursor.description`.

It should have elements:

```
name
table_oid
attribute_number
data_type_oid
data_type_size
type_modifier
format_code
```